# Qustion about Ideal...(Ring theory)

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I know that if $I,J$ are Ideals of $R$ so $I+J=\left\{i+j|i\in I, j\in J\right\}$ is Ideal to...
I need to find $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\left<a\right>=\left<84\right>+\left<330\right>$.

I don't understand the meaning, I'll be glad if you will help me...
Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity ?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, I know about it, but how it's helps me at this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you probably mean "ideal" instead of "idealizer".

Secondly, The symbol $\langle 84\rangle$ means the ideal
$$
\{84x : x\in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
So you are looking at the ideal
$$
I+J = \{84x + 330y : x,y\in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
Now since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, $\exists a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $I+J = \langle a\rangle$.

Now, $84 = 84\cdot 1 + 330\cdot 0 \in I+J$, so $a\mid 84$. Similarly, $a\mid 330$.

Now can you prove, together with Bezout's identity that $a = GCD(84,330)$?

Comment: What is PID? I see the connection but I don't understand the whole picture - How Bezout's identity helps me here? it's because $84\cdot a+330\cdot b=\gcd(84,330)$? Thank you!

Comment: But why this is mean that this is Ideal? if $6=\gcd(84,330)$ the ideal is $6$? I still don't understand why this is the ideal...
Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman PID = Principal Ideal Domain. It means any ideal can be generated by a single element. You can use mutual inclusion or the minimality of <6> (it's the 'smallest' ideal containing 6) to show the ideals are the same.

Comment: @G.H.Faust, can you explain me more please? I didn't understand your last sentence "You can use mutual inclusion or the minimality of <6> (it's the 'smallest' ideal containing 6) to show the ideals are the same." Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman if A and B are sets where A is a subset of B, and B is a subset of A, then A = B. This is what I refer to by mutual inclusion.

Minimality of <c> refers to the fact that if there is some other ideal I with c in I, then <c> is a subset of I.

Comment: @G.H.Faust, So I need to prove that $A=B$??

Comment: @YoavFridman Well, the problem is finding an element 'a' such that <a> = <84>+<330>. Once you have the idea for what 'a' is, all you need to do is prove they're equal. So if you let A = <a> and B = <84>+<330>, yes.

Comment: @G.H.Faust, but how this is connect to the fact that their are ideals?

Comment: @G.H.Faust, can you help me with the proof? (that they are equals). Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman The best way to get help is to be very precise about what work you have done, and what step you are stuck at—and this probably requires working for more than 5 minutes before asking a question!  You are trying to show that two ideals are equal, and to do so, you must show containment in two directions.  So, which direction is harder for you?

Comment: @YoavFridman After a point, it kinda doesn't matter that they're ideals. Ultimately, an ideal is just a set.

Comment: @G.H.Faust, I'll try and I'll tell you...

Comment: @G.H.Faust, I know that 12 hours past, but I'll be glad if you will help me with this direction: $\left<6\right>\subseteq \left<84\right>+\left<330\right>$. Thank you!

Comment: @G.H.Faust, I not sure if is this direction, but I meant to the direction that we have to use Bezout's identity... Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman Well, like I said, <6> has the nice property that if 6 in in another ideal, <6> is a subset of that ideal. Is there any reason Bezout's identity would suggest 6 is in <84>+<330>?